# The difference betweenサポートに問い合わせ/サポートに問い合わせる?

Tags: verbs

My guess is that “サポートに問い合わせ” is a noun phrase, while “サポートに問い合わせる” is a verb phrase.
I saw it written as “問い合わせ” on a button in one app and have noticed similar patterns with different Japanese verbs too.
My question is: why not go with the verb 問い合わせる? Is it the same as with sino-japanese verbs, such as 表示 or 削除 when written in UI without する?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as you understand it correctly 問い合わせ is the noun corresponding to 問い合わせる.

It can be seen as 問い合わせをする with (を)する dropped, just like 表示(する) or 削除(する). It is common in instructions/commands possibly because it is more succinct (other examples: ここをクリック, ウェブで検索 etc.).